# Image setting inside a custom framework

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set image inside my custom framework I am using following method to set it. It is working everywhere but not working in my custom `UITableViewCell`.

```
self.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"image",in: Bundle(for: type(of: self)), compatibleWith: nil)
```

Error I am getting:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSInteger' (aka 'Int')

Why it is not working in UITableViewCell.

Comment: When say custom framework you mean custom cell?

Comment: No custom cell inside a custom framework.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have solved it myself.

Instead of calling this way.

```
self.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"image",in: Bundle(for: type(of: self)), compatibleWith: nil)
```

Change it to:

```
self.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"image",in: Bundle(for: MyCustomCell.self), compatibleWith: nil)
```

This is working.